# Python recursion with shared state: inner function vs passing in parameters?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree, python-itertools, fold

What are the space / time tradeoffs for each approach?

Suppose I have a tree-reduce function:
This is similar to a list fold / reduce, but takes a ternary rather than binary function. Since the *function* and the *unit* state will be shared throughout the recursive calls, should I embed them in an outer function like this:

```
def tree_fold(f, unit, root):
    def fold(node):
        if not node:
            return unit
        else:
            return f(*map(fold, (node.left, node.right)), node)
    return fold(root)
```

... or pass it by reference like this?

```
def fold(f, unit, node):
    if not node:
        return unit
    else:
        return f(*[fold(f, unit, n) for n in (node.left, node.right)], node)
```

If there is another approach that is more pythonic, I'll be happy to see it!

Comment: Precisely what do you mean by "*more efficient*"? Least time? Least memory space? Easiest to maintain? Fewest lines of code?

Comment: @Robᵩ I'm wondering what the space / time trade offs are, will update the question.

Comment: Worrying about passing individual references is a micro-optimization that is *very* unlikely to produce noticeable benefit

Comment: @MisterMiyagi so would you recommend the second approach for concision?